# Cannot perform ember data queries/rest call inside Ember.service

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using ember 2.12

Here's my route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    rentalService: Ember.inject.service('rentals-service'),

    model(){
        this.get('rentalService').findRentals();
        console.log('Inside route');
        console.log(this.get('store'));
        return this.get('store').findAll('rental');
  }
});
```

Here's my ember rental-service

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  findRentals() {
    console.log("Inside servce");
    console.log(this.get('store'));
    return "hello from servce";
  }
});
```

Why is it I cannot access the ember-data on the rental-service? whenever I console .log `this.get('store')` inside the rental-service it returns an undefined. However on the routes, whenever I console.log the same code it returns this value.

Does this mean I cannot perform a rest call using ember data inside a service?

[image]

I'm using Mirage to mock a web-server/http requests

Comment: By default ember will inject `store`only to controllers and routes, which means you have access to store service only in controllers and routes by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the store inside an ember component/service. A workaround for this is to retrieve the store via dependency injection.

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),

  findRentals() {
    console.log("Inside service");
    console.log(this.get('store'));
    return "hello from service";
  }
});
```

Be wary if you have another service with a name of `store`, it might fetch that one.